# Query para obtener el Cliente con mayor idCliente sin usar función Max()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dada la tabla:

Cliente(idCliente as int, Nombre as string, Direccion as string)

¿como hago un Query para obtener el Cliente con mayor idCliente SIN USAR LA FUNCION MAX()?

No se me ocurre ninguna manera, espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos!

Comment: haciendo un `top 1` mas un `order by desc idCliente`. Y cual seria el objetivo??

Answer (score 3):

con hacer un top 1 en el select y ordenando descendientemente por el idCliente es sufieciente:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM Cliente c ORDER BY c.idCliente DESC;
```

Comment: que no le faltan los campos a ese select?

Comment: @henry-steven-salazar-serrano agrega las columnas al SELECT